# LWJGL doesnt draw outside Display Mode

Tags: java, opengl, game-engine, lwjgl

When I try to move an opengl quad outside the size of the main window, it doesn't render.

Say if I have a window 600x800. Then I resize it to be full screen. Once I move the quad(player) outside the defined window properties, it disappears.
I think this is essential because I'm working on a top down RPG and he will be moving around on the x and y plane. Also if that isn't enough, how would I make a camera that keeps the player in the center...
So far I have

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 845, 0, 520, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

I havent been able to test it due to the first problem

Comment: Can you include the code that you actually use when you resize the window to fullscreen? In addition to changing the projection matrix, you also need to set the viewport. The viewport will restrict the region of the window that things are projected onto, you generally need to set both the projection matrix and the viewport when you resize the window. In fact, setting the viewport is the more important of the two operations since sometimes you do not want to change the projected coordinates but you definitely want to project everything onto the full window.

Answer (score 0):

On the part to keep the camera in the center. Just translate everything -x, -y relative to the camera/player's position.

```
    glTranslatef(-cameraX, -cameraY, 0);
```

So when you move the player change the players position and translate everything the opposite way.